# OpenCV installation problem in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: opencv

I have downloaded opencv from github. I am following the installation instruction from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV). Ubuntu 13.04 64bit system hangs when i run the following command (after 25% complete)

```
make -j
```

Additional information:

```
3.8.0-31-generic
LSB Version:    core-2.0-amd64:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-amd64:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-amd64:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:    13.04
Codename:   raring
```

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution. `make -j` is not right. It should have some number after `j` like the following

```
make -j2
```

The above command means run `make` on two parallel threads. I have suggested an edit to the writer of opencv wiki.